# Count occurences of a special character in a file

Tags: bash, count, ascii

I am writing a bash script that will count occurences of [], (), {}, '', "", `` and // so that i can debug other scripts for missing one of them.
Here is the code:

```
a=0; b=0; cc=0; d=0; e=0; f=0; g=0; h=0; i=0; j=0   # set default values
squote=`echo -e "\x27"`
dquote=`echo -e "\x22"`

while IFS= read -r -n1 c; do
  [ "$c" == "[" ] && (( a++ ))
  [ "$c" == "]" ] && (( b++ ))
  [ "$c" == "(" ] && (( cc++ ))     # i imported this line from another online script, is there a reason why the author avoids (( c++ )) ?
  [ "$c" == ")" ] && (( d++ ))
  [ "$c" == "{" ] && (( e++ ))
  [ "$c" == "}" ] && (( f++ ))
  [ "$c" == "\x27" ] && (( g++ ))    # single quote
  [ "$c" == "$dquote" ] && (( h++ ))  # double quote
  [ "$c" == '`' ] && (( i++ ))        # back tick
  [ "$c" == '/' ] && (( j++ ))        # forward slash
done < "$1"

echo '[]'="$a,$b"
echo '()'="$cc,$d"
echo '{}'="$e,$f"
echo "$squote" ="$g"
echo "$dquote" ="$h"
echo '``'="$i"
echo '/'="$j"      # when used this way: /hello/
```

Questions:
1) why the cc++ instead of c++
2) why some results don't come out right at all.
3) How to annotate the special characters the right way.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, you are already using `c` as the character you read from the file; you can't use the same name for the `(` counter.

Comment: I think it's time i take a break D)

Comment: You are right, it does not show above. I was simply using g=$(tr -cd '\x27' < $1 | wc -c) later in the script to verify the above results.

Answer (score 1):

some simplifications and functional script

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0; b=0; c=0; d=0; e=0; f=0; g=0; h=0; i=0; j=0

while read -r -n1 char; do
    case "$char" in
        "[" ) (( a++ )) ;;
        "]" ) (( b++ )) ;;
        "(" ) (( c++ )) ;;
        ")" ) (( d++ )) ;;
        "{" ) (( e++ )) ;;
        "}" ) (( f++ )) ;;
        "'" ) (( g++ )) ;;
        '"' ) (( h++ )) ;;
        '`' ) (( i++ )) ;;
        '/' ) (( j++ )) ;;
    esac
done <<< "[]{}()/"$'\x60'$'\x22'$'\x27'     # $'\x60' == backtick

echo '[]'="$a,$b"
echo '()'="$c,$d"
echo '{}'="$e,$f"
echo "'" ="$g"
echo '"' ="$h"
echo '`'="$i"
echo '/'="$j"
```

output

```
[]=1,1
()=1,1
{}=1,1
' =1
" =1
`=1
/=1
```

nota:

```
 prefer:  dquote=$( echo -e "\x22" )   # and not ``
 better:  dquote=$'\x22'    # or \042 octal
 simpler: dquote='"'
```

to check script and learn, I suggest to install **shellcheck** or use https://www.shellcheck.net/

initially:

```
    [ "$char" == "[" ] && (( a++ ))
    [ "$char" == "]" ] && (( b++ ))
    [ "$char" == "(" ] && (( c++ ))
    [ "$char" == ")" ] && (( d++ ))
    [ "$char" == "{" ] && (( e++ ))
    [ "$char" == "}" ] && (( f++ ))
    [ "$char" == "'" ] && (( g++ ))
    [ "$char" == '"' ] && (( h++ ))
    [ "$char" == '`' ] && (( i++ ))
    [ "$char" == '/' ] && (( j++ ))
```

but unnecessary tests are systematically performed.
we can also use:

```
    if [[ $char == "[" ]]; then (( a++ ))
    elif [[ $char == "]" ]]; then (( b++ ))
    ...
```

but performances with 10,000 iterations:

```
   if   > if elif > case  
6720 ms > 2895 ms > 2073 ms
```

Comment: Even better would be a `case` statement; only one of those `test` commands will be true. `case $char in "[") (( a++ )) ;; "]") ((b++)) ;; ... esac`.

Comment: @kyodev: I wrote this script because in a much longer one I was getting the 'syntax error: unexpected end of file' error where a missing closing ) ] ' " is often the reason for the fail. Thanks for the changes: $char instead of $c; the <<< which i would never have thought of using (for other scripts), the great shellcheck suggestion and for the whole solution which works beautifully now!

Comment: So using [[ does an if comparaison AND a verify in one go? Also, which of [ "$char" == "[" ] && (( a++ )) OR case/esac construct as suggested by chepner is faster for long texts/scripts?

Comment: sorry, I used [[  just for avoid the quotes around variables, just cosmétic

Comment: yes, case is more 3x faster than all if tests, so visible for long texts/scripts